# g++ stack unwinding

Tags: g++

Is there any way to disable the stack unwinding feature of `g++`?

Comment: what are you trying to do, and why is "stack unwinding" getting in the way?

Comment: O.O Who and why would want that?

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to "disable" at just one point -- maybe to effect a quick emergency exit from a module? -- you might consider using setjmp and longjmp from the C std library.

Comment: I don't think that jump would help, if this is C++ (as the tag is g++)

Comment: I think to rewrite my code in c is better than this way. I don't required to use the c++ exception in this module.

Comment: @Kiril: Well, if the goal is to return from a function (or a stack of function calls) without calling destructors, then yes, it would. That's normally the reason why you should *not* use longjmp in C++, since it doesn't call destructors as the stack is unwound. But for this poster, perhaps that's precisely why it *would* help.

Comment: @Peica: that's certainly an option too!

Comment: @Ernest - I didn't know that *longjmp* will **not** call the destructors.. how is this possible :^) Then using "longjmp" is very dangerous and you should really know what you're doing, before using it. Anyway, thanks for that info!

Comment: In face,my real purpose is to static link libstdc++ with my legacy c++ code. So another option is use c to rewrite it.